# Optional Column Name for Table.NestedJoin with an Inner JoinKind

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

In the query below I perform a join on a the Rep table with the Customer to exclude Reps that do not have any customers assigned.

```
let
...
  merge_customer = Table.NestedJoin(
    select_columns,{"RepCode"},
    Customer,{"CustomerRepCode"},
    "Customer",
    JoinKind.Inner
  ),
  remove_join_column = Table.RemoveColumns(
    merge_customer,
    {"Customer"}
  )
in
  remove_join_column
```

Because it is an inner join I don't need the resulting `Customer` column. I then delete that column.

Is there a way to shorten this? I have tried excluding the new column name `Customer` or passing in null and it only generates an error.

I appreciate this may just not be possible due to the language being quite young but thought I may have missed something in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Table.Join might do what you want, or after the result of Table.NestedJoin you can add a custom column that calls Table.RemoveColumns on the table column. That would probably look like this (didn't verify the code works):

```
Table.AddCustomColumn(merge_customer, "InnerColumnRemoved", each Table.RemoveColumns([RepCode], {"Customer"}))
```

And then you would remove the RepCode column